# unproportional scaling with fabric

Tags: fabricjs

I have a situation where I don't want to scale the object proportionally using Fabric.js when the object's corner is dragged. Is it possible to turn of proportional scaling for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late, but you can use the `uniScaleTransform` property of the canvas.

```
canvas.uniScaleTransform = true;  // Disable proportional scaling
canvas.uniScaleTransform = false; // Enable proportional scaling
```

[fabric docs](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4)

Comment: Is it possible to enable / disable proportional scaling for just some elements on the canvas not the whole canvas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to do it for specific objects, but you could just toggle uniScaleTransform on the whole canvas for certain objects on selection and then listen for object:selected or selection:cleared to toggle back.